# Replace '\n' with <br> in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have `var recommend = 'I recommended Garden Solutions for this Tender Contracting on the basis of\n\n1)Top Scorer for tender\n2)Professional Experience in Building Services\n3)Approved Service Providers';`

I want to replace `\n` with an HTML break and want to display it as below:

> I recommended Garden Solutions for this Tender Contracting on the basis of
>
> 1)Top Scorer for tender
>
> 2)Professional Experience in Building Services
>
> 3)Approved Service Providers

I am using JavaScript's  replace function

```
var val = recommend.replace("\n","<br>");
```

But it's not working.

Comment: You need to insert it into the DOM.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read line break in a string with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784313/read-line-break-in-a-string-with-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript replace newline escape sequence with newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988686/javascript-replace-newline-escape-sequence-with-newline)

Answer (score 7):

Use a regular expression (`RegExp`) literal and the "global" (`g`) modifier:

```
var val = recommend.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
```

Or use a [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) directly:

```
var val = recommend.replace(RegExp("\n","g"), "<br>");
```

Answer (score 1):

By using the RegExp `"\n"` you just replace the first occurrence. To replace all occurrences you need to add RegExp the modifier `g`.

So use the following, instead, to replace all occurrences:

```
var val = recommend.replace( new RegExp( "\n", "g" ),"<br>");
```

[Demo fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/TSNwU/).

Comment: yes, I have checked working on demo fiddle. But not working on my file. not replacing '\n' with new line

Comment: @Navdeep Maybe you should put a fiddle on with _some_ of your code. The method here is correct, so your error must be somewhere else.