# JavaScript replace newline escape sequence with newline

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to replace any occurrences of the string "\n" with the new line character: '\n'.

`replace(/[\\n]/g, "\n")`
doesn't seem to work.

I'm unfamiliar with regex and was wondering if someone could help.

Comment: You don't need a regular expression for this.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Then please give me another method. I'll mark it as the answer if correct.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`[\\n]` is the set of the characters `\` and `n`. Just take off the brackets:

```
….replace(/\\n/g, '\n')
```

In modern JavaScript environments, you can use [`String.prototype.replaceAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) (ES2021) instead:

```js
….replaceAll('\\n', '\n')
```

Comment: A regular expression solution is perfectly valid here. This is a perfectly fine use case for it.

Answer (score 5):

## Don't abuse regex!

If you are testing for single strings, test for single strings.

Since JavaScript doesn't have a built in `replaceAll` method (yet) for strings, you can make your own:

```
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(find, replace) {
    return this.split(find).join(replace);
};
```

Then just call it like this:

```
mystring.replaceAll('\\n', '\n'); // for the "find" argument, you need to escape the backslash
```

Of course, if you don't like fiddling with the prototype (there are reasons to, and not to - decide yourself), you can define it as a regular function:

```
function replaceAll(string, find, replace) {
    return string.split(find).join(replace);
}
```

Then call it like this:

```
replaceAll(mystring, '\\n', '\n');
```

Comment: `.replace` seems to be more efficient than `split` and `join`: http://jsperf.com/replaceall29 (I don't see the reason of not using regex...)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/ Not using rejex is beautiful!

Comment: @bjb568: In an “enlightenment” sort of way, or visually? The difference here is literally `(/\\n/g` versus `All('\\n'`.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Not sure we should be concerned about "efficiency" unless it's either explicitly stated or it is obvious that OP is going to operate on large strings.

Comment: @minitech I personally think it's easier to read. Rejex seems... too powerful for such a simple task.

Comment: @minitech In an "enlightenment" sort of way. OP was *just* confused because of the regular expression. And this is only a trivial example... what if one day they will need to replace stuff with regex metacharacters inside? They will [miserably fail to do proper escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24911753/regex-in-java-for-a-specific-specific-string) and stuff.

Comment: @bjb568 - Not using regex is ugly. Also splitting and joining strings are not a good replacement for regular expressions.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 "splitting and joining strings are not a good replacement for regular expressions" - sure, but this task does not require the use of regular expressions. So, we are not **replacing** them, we are solving a different problem. Would you never walk just because "feet are not good replacements for cars"?

Comment: Looks like this is turning into an unexpected argument... What I am trying say is just don't over-complicate the problem. Regex is better and easier to read, most importantly it is made to do this kind of task and might be optimized by the browser.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 The whole basis for this argument is that *not everybody agrees that not using regex over-complicates the problem*. Some people prefer not using regex for the same reasons you use regex - readability is very subjective.

Comment: It's like you are reinventing the wheel. But hey, we will just leave it to OP to decide.

Comment: I would definitely _not_ recommend extending the native prototype for this sort of thing. Especially since it might be added in a future version of ECMAScript and this, especially being unguarded can mess with its behavior.

Comment: No extending native prototype. I was just shat on (for good reason) for doing this recently. It's not future-proof at all.

Comment: Using regular expressions to replace regular strings in a string is also definitely not abuse.

Comment: @Nick How so? The worst that can reasonably happen is that an awesome new method with the same name is introduced and you safely override it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum In my eyes, it is.

Comment: And now I come back in the morning and a correct answer is now voted lower than two that are actually wrong. This is weird. Perhaps you could take it off the prototype, anyways?

Comment: @minitech I voted down because I'm in agreeance that the prototype should not be extended for this. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Unbelievable, this got actually 12 down votes for wisely knowing not to abuse with regex. Unbelievable

Comment: @ValentinMercier: I think it was probably mostly about native prototypes, considering that it’s 10 now within 14 minutes. Also, I hope you don’t mind if I edit that comment a bit.

Comment: @minitech Yeah I'm sorry for that. Indeed now it's ten. It used to be 12 though

Comment: And now someone posted this answer on reddit... http://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/2byq3u/splitjoin_vs_replace_some_microoptimizers_just/

Comment: `String.prototype.split` and `Array.prototype.join` were never meant to be used for this purpose. I would argue that this is more of an "abuse" than using a global regexp is (*which is not an abuse at all*).

Comment: @nderscore What do you mean they weren't made for this purpose? They aren't made for any specific purpose. Regex *is* tho. Regex is a matching pattern representing a range of possible strings, not just one.

Comment: @bjb568 `split` is meant to split a string into an array on substrings. `join` is meant to join the elements on an array into a single string. Multiple instances of a single string **is** a pattern to be matched, so a RegExp is completely valid.

Comment: @nderscore I know what split and join *do*, but since arrays can be used for many purposes, splitting and joining have many purposes too, they aren't "made" for any one in particular. Who's talking about *multiple* instances of a *single* string? I'm talking about the opposite.

Comment: @nderscore using `.split(val).join(otherval)` is actually a pretty common and well known techniques. I completely agree that using regular expressions here is not abuse but if you avoid regular expressions this is likely the simplest way to do so.

Comment: I've made an edit, feel free to revert it if you don't like it.

Comment: @Benjamin That is... Way too much change.

Comment: @bjb568 fair enough, please do steal parts you want from that edit.  Namely the part calling it 'abuse' is a bit silly in my opinion - discussing the pros and cons of using regex to address the problem here and coming to the conclusion (you believe) that it is better to avoid it.

Comment: @Benjamin Meh, nah. Also, your edit would fail if the spec defined the arguments for a future `replaceAll` different from mine.

Comment: @bjb568 your prototype extension would break any other piece of code that uses strings in JavaScript or including libraries that do so in the application. I don't think that's better. What about logging a warning for the very least?

Comment: @Benjamin Well, won't break my code, since I have this standard and don't use libraries :P Why log a warning if you get an error anyway?

Comment: @bjb568 the thing is - something like `.replaceAll` is likely to apprear in EcmaScript 6 or EcmaScript7. This means that one day without warning all your code doing this can break when Chrome updates to support it. This happened to a lot of people when `.trim` was added and then when `.find` was recently added to arrays.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58252/discussion-between-bjb568-and-benjamin-gruenbaum).

Answer (score 0):

**for React users**
You can replace \n with 
then you can use renderHTML library to render the content

example :

```
textWithLineBreaker.split("\n").join("<br/>")
```

then in the render method use

```
{renderHTML(textWithLineBreaker)}
```